# iOS 13 Accessibility voice control function

Tags: accessibility, ios13, voice-control

Is the iOS 13 accessibility voice control function source code or a related API open for use by developers?
I want to write some like this:
[Accessibility voice control use screen tab number to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkmCD.jpg)

Comment: Please replace "enter image description here" with a description of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is highlighted about this iOS 13 new feature but its ['accessibilityUserInputLabels'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/3197989-accessibilityuserinputlabels?language=objc) property that enables changing labels specifically for some items: neither [event name](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/criteria-ios.html#accessibility-options) nor [notification](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#accessibility-options) are exposed.

In iOS 13, you **can't have this feature under control to code something specific**: the system analyzes your app and applies labels, numbers and actions to the appropriate elements.

The only thing to be customized is the [vocal command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57902292/3825084) inside the device settings: forget about coding anything about the voice control... until the next iOS version maybe?  ;o)